# how to check letter inside word[hangman]

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to my button can check if the letter is inside the word for example

```
word: Hai
user pres btnA
result : _a_
user pres btnH
result : Ha_
```

this what i do at kotlin Android studio

```
 fun guessTry(click : View){
        val guessW = txtKata.toString()
        txtKata.text = null
        if (click == btnA){
            val a = btnA.text
            if(a in secretWord.toLowerCase() || a in secretWord.toUpperCase() ){
                corecGuess.add(guessW)
                wordSecret()
            }
        }
}
```

```
word: Hai
user pres btnA
result : _a_
user pres btnH
result : Ha_
```

Comment: You could use `.contains()` method to check if a word contains a certain letter.

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to change the if function like this

```
fun guessTry(click : View){
        val guessW = txtKata.toString()
        txtKata.text = null
        if (click == btnA){
            val a = btnA.text
            if(secretWord.toLowerCase().contains(a) || secretWord.toUpperCase().contains(a)  ){
                corecGuess.add(guessW)
                wordSecret()
            }
        }
}
```